# Elasticsearch aggregation on array items

Tags: elasticsearch, aggregation, elasticsearch-net

Given below is my Elasticsearch document on which I want to fire an aggregation query.

```json
{
  "id": 1,
  "attributes": [
    {
      "fieldId": 1,
      "value": "Male"
    },
    {
      "fieldId": 2,
      "value": "12/11/2015"
    }
  ]
}
```

```json
{
  "id": 2,
  "attributes": [
    {
      "fieldId": 1,
      "value": "Male"
    },
    {
      "fieldId": 2,
      "value": "11/11/2015"
    }
  ]
}
```

The result has to be as follows.

```json
[
  {
    "key": "Male",
    "doc_count": 1
  }
]
```

```json
[
  {
    "key": "12/11/2015",
    "doc_count": 1
  },
  {
    "key": "11/11/2015",
    "doc_count": 1
  }
]
```

Is there a way that this can be achieved in Elasticsearch?

Comment: Should `doc_count` of `Male` be 2?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That's possible. See this example:

We have to map attributes as `nested` type to be able to aggregate properly.

```js
PUT /test
{
  "mappings": {
    "sample": {
      "properties": {
        "id": {
          "type": "integer"
        },
        "attributes": {
          "type": "nested",
          "properties": {
            "fieldId": {
              "type": "integer"
            },
            "value": {
              "type": "string",
              "index": "not_analyzed"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Let's add your given test data:

```js
PUT /test/sample/1
{"id":1,"attributes":[{"fieldId":1,"value":"Male"},{"fieldId":2,"value":"12/11/2015"}]}
PUT /test/sample/2
{"id":2,"attributes":[{"fieldId":1,"value":"Male"},{"fieldId":2,"value":"11/11/2015"}]}
```

And finally let's run this query:

```js
GET /test/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  },
  "aggs": {
    "Nest": {
      "nested": {
        "path": "attributes"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "fieldIds": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "attributes.fieldId",
            "size": 0
          },
          "aggs": {
            "values": {
              "terms": {
                "field": "attributes.value",
                "size": 0
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

What will it do?

1. Run `nested` aggregation first in order to get into `nested` objects and aggregate them properly.
2. Create buckets using `terms` aggregation for each `fieldId`, in your case we'll get two of them: `1` and `2`.
3. Run `terms` aggregation again for each of buckets above in order to get coresponding values.

So that's the output.

```js
{
  "took": 2,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 2,
    "max_score": 0,
    "hits": []
  },
  "aggregations": {
    "Nest": {
      "doc_count": 4,
      "fieldIds": {
        "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
        "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
        "buckets": [
          {
            "key": 1,
            "doc_count": 2,
            "values": {
              "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
              "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
              "buckets": [
                {
                  "key": "Male",
                  "doc_count": 2
                }
              ]
            }
          },
          {
            "key": 2,
            "doc_count": 2,
            "values": {
              "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
              "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
              "buckets": [
                {
                  "key": "11/11/2015",
                  "doc_count": 1
                },
                {
                  "key": "12/11/2015",
                  "doc_count": 1
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

It's not precisely what you've requested. But that's closest what you can get in Elasticsearch.